# Handling authentication

Tags: authentication, backend

I recently learned a lot about the authentication/authorization subjects, but I am still having several questions, that would help to clear the things up in my head.

**User Authentication**

As far as I read, the most common authentication patterns are:

- Single token authentication, based on a session data stored on the server side.
- Authorization/Refresh tokens

**Session**

Is the implementation of the session storage required while handling Auth/Refresh token pattern? Some sources I read implemented it, some not and I am still unsure about it.

**Authorization / Refresh tokens**

As far as I read, refresh token have been always returned to the client. Does an implementation of storing particular refresh token in the server cache (i.e. Redis) make any sense?

I am asking as I think that idea would strengthen an overall server security, reduce the risk of stealing the refresh token from the user, etc., but I believe it could have a negative impact on the caching storage (there should be the way of removing refresh tokens when users i.e. closes the browser, and I am not talking about blacklisting as we do not exactly know when the user does it).

**Blacklisting tokens**

I have been trying to implement blacklisting both for refresh and auth tokens. Is it really necessary to focus on blacklisting auth tokens or is this solution too verbose? I mean, I understand the importance of blacklisting refresh tokens as they are long-lived, but I believe blacklisting auth tokens would add unnecessary logic to the authentication.

Are there any other important things/ideas that I could probably miss?
Any response would be appreciated. I need to sort these things as I do not want to mess up during implementation. :)